# Android when I try to merge 2 waves files the output contains only the first wave

Tags: java, android, wav

I am working on android. I want to merge two wave files and want to create a third file. For this, I create two input streams and then trying to write those input streams into one output stream file. the result I get always contains just 1 of the two files and it ignores the second one

**This is my code:-**

```
  try {
                      //first file
                FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(recordPath+"/test2.wav"); 
                     //second file 
                FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(recordPath+"/test.wav");   
                    //concatenate the two files
                SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fis1,fis2);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(recordPath+"/finaloutput.wav")); 
                int temp;
                try {
                    while ((temp = sis.read())!= -1){
                        fos.write(temp);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: You cannot concatanate 2 `wav` files as if they are strings. The file contains a header, describing the properties of the audio in it, so you'll have to create a new header. Also, both files must have the same sampling rate, bit depth and number of channels. If not - you'll have to convert one of them to match the other. I suggest you to read about `wav` file structure and then decide if you want to do it by yourself or to find a library that does it.

Comment: is there a library I can use? I am on using java in android studio